# Setting default System.exit codes in Java?

Tags: java, console, system.exit

I have a C# app that runs a jar file and uses the `System.exit` code as a return value. A console window is displayed as a part of this jar, and if the user closes it (thereby terminating the jar) it returns an exit code of `143`. The problem is that `143` (or any positive integer) could be a valid exit code if the jar completes successfully.

I need a way to manually set the System.exit code to a negative integer. Treating `143` as an exception in the C# app is out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in Diego Dias [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163629/setting-default-system-exit-codes-in-java/2163704#2163704),

> The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.

If you really want to ignore that, and both the Java and the C# apps are in your hand, an easy workaround is to add `1000` to your `System.exit` return value in Java, when the jar completes.

Your C# application will recognize the successful execution by a return code `>= 1000` and subtract it again. `143` is below `1000` and thus an error.

Comment: Since I own both the Java and C# code, this is a trivial fix to implement. Goes to show that sometimes the simplest solution is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the [java documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) you can use System.exit(int n), so just put a negative number as a parameter, also by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.

Comment: I am already able to return the proper codes using System.exit() if the jar completes, but if the user terminates the jar prematurely, I have no control over what is returned.

Comment: So your problem is another one ...
You need to identify a "close or exit" event on your application and throw an exception that could use system.exit

Comment: I thought of using a negative number too, but some systems cannot handle this (e.g. OSX)